Find $\mathbb{E}(T|x_i=c_i,\ i =\overline{1..5})$
Problem statement:
Let $T \sim U[0, 1]$ and $\forall \, i = \overline{1\dots 5}, \, x_i \sim U[0, T]$. It is known that $x_i$ are independent. Find $\mathbb{E}(T|x_i=c_i,\ i =\overline{1\dots 5})$, where $ c_i \in [0, 1]$.
I've managed to find the distribution of each $x_i$, i.e. $p_{x_i}(x) = -\ln(x)\mathbb{1}_{[0, 1]}(x)$. But I'm really stuck on what to do next. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

$T$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.
Conditioned on $T$, $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are IID $U[0,T]$. This can be rephrased as follows. Let $U_1,\dots,U_n$ be IID $[0,1]$. Then letting $X_j = T U_j$ gives RVs $X_1,\dots,X_n$ with the desired properties.
Let's continue. Let $f(x_1,\dots,x_n,t)$ be the joint density for $(T,X_1,\dots, X_n)$. The assumption is
$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n | t) =  \frac{1}{t^n} \prod_{j=1}^n {\bf 1}_{[0,t]}(x_j).$$
Since $t$ is $U[0,1]$, we conclude
$$(*) \quad f(x_1,\dots,x_n,t) = f(x_1,\dots,x_n | t) f_T(t) = \left ( \frac{1}{t^n} \prod_{j=1}^n {\bf 1}_{[0,t]}(x_j)\right){\bf 1}_{[0,1]}(t).$$
Let's assume $t,x_1,\dots,x_n$ in $[0,1]$ b/c o/w $f$ is zero. Then the  product of indicators on the right hand side of $(*)$ is equal to $1$ if and only if for $j=1,\dots, n$, $x_j\le t$, equivalently, $\max (x_1,\dots,x_n) \le t$ and is otherwise $0$.  we can therefore rewrite $(*)$ as
$$ f(x_1,\dots,x_n,t) = t^{-n} {\bf 1}_{[0,t]} (\max (x_1,\dots,x_n))= t^{-n} {\bf 1}_{[\max(x_1,\dots,x_n),1]}(t),~t,x_1,\dots,x_n \in [0,1].$$
The joint density of $X_1,\dots,X_n$, $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is equal to
$$ \int_0^1 f(x_1,\dots,x_n,t) dt = \int_{\max(x_1,\dots,x_n)}^1 t^{-n} dt=\begin{cases} - \ln (\max(x_1,\dots,x_n))& n=1 \\ \frac{\max(x_1,\dots,x_n)^{1-n}-1}{n-1}  & n>1\end{cases}$$
Let's continue with the case $n>1$, corresponding to the OP's original question:
$$ f(t|x_1,\dots,x_n) = \frac{f(x_1,\dots,x_n,t)}{f(x_1,\dots,x_n)} = \frac{n-1}{t^n} \frac{ {\bf 1}_{[\max (x_1,\dots,x_n),1]} (t)}{\max(x_1,\dots,x_n)^{1-n}-1}.$$
Specifically, if $\max(x_1,\dots,x_n)=m$, the density is
$$ f(t|x_1,\dots,x_n) = \frac{n-1}{m^{1-n}-1}\frac{1}{t^{n}}\mbox{ on }[m,1]$$
and zero otherwise. The desired conditional expectation in this case is $\int t f(t| x_1,\dots,x_n) dt$ which is equal to
$$\frac{n-1}{m^{1-n} -1}  \int_m^1 t^{1-n} dt = ...$$
For $n>2$ we get
$$ \frac{n-1}{m^{1-n}-1}\times \frac{m^{2-n}-1}{n-2}= \frac{n-1}{n-2}\times \frac{m-m^{n-1}}{1-m^{n-1}}. $$

Absolutely brilliant. Thank you so much!

The OP says that the $X_i$ are independent, not conditionally independent.

They are defined as uniform on $[0,T]$. Since $T$ is not deterministic, they  cannot be independent, only conditionally independent. To see this, calculate the expectation of $X_1X_2$ and see it is not the expectation of $X_1$ times the expectation of $X_2$.
